# It is an eyelash question when importing SFM(Source Filmmaker) characters into Blender

Tags: texturing, import

The eyelash part was strangely applied when importing the SFM([Source Filmmaker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m4grd.jpg)) character into Blender. The eyelash texture is supposed to be included in "face.png". I have not been able to advance for a week due to lack of knowledge. I searched SFM into Blender related courses multiple times on Google and YouTube. I've seen a lot of related videos, but I can not find a solution.

Compressed file I worked on (Blender, texture, etc) link:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/1r3c4iv2d8f2bfu/2b.zip?dl=0

Original SFM character source address:

https://sfmlab.com/item/2087/

[image]
[image]

Comment: A more detailed description of the actual problem would be useful. What do you wish to achieve? What is it that you do and how exactly does the result differ from your expectations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the "Hair1" texture and this node set.

[image]

Comment: Thanks to josh sanfelici. You are a genius.